# NFTs displayed in a collection

Tags: web3js, nft, dapps, router

I want to display all the NFTs with the same collection name on my marketplace however I get nothing displayed, I have a home page where it displays each collection as a card and I have a collection page where it is supposed to display all the NFTs with the same collection name. I also do have App page that routes between home and collection page and here is the code for the 3 pages.

Home.js:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import { Row, Col, Card, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = ({ marketplace, nft }) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  const loadMarketplaceItems = async () => {
    // Load all unsold items
    const itemCount = await marketplace.itemCount();
    let items = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= itemCount; i++) {
      const item = await marketplace.items(i);
      if (!item.sold) {
        // get uri url from nft contract
        const uri = await nft.tokenURI(item.tokenId);
        // use uri to fetch the nft metadata stored on ipfs
        const response = await fetch(uri);
        const metadata = await response.json();
        // get total price of item (item price + fee)
        const totalPrice = await marketplace.getTotalPrice(item.itemId);
        // Add item to items array
        items.push({
          totalPrice,
          collectionName: metadata.collectionName,
          itemId: item.itemId,
          seller: item.seller,
          name: metadata.name,
          description: metadata.description,
          image: metadata.image,
        });
      }
    }
    setLoading(false);
    setItems(items);
  };

  const buyMarketItem = async (item) => {
    await (
      await marketplace.purchaseItem(item.itemId, { value: item.totalPrice })
    ).wait();
    loadMarketplaceItems();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadMarketplaceItems();
  }, []);

  if (loading === false && !items.length) {
    return (
      <main style={{ padding: "1rem 0" }}>
        <h2>No Items in the Marketplace</h2>
      </main>
    );
  }

  const renderCollectionCards = () => {
    const collectionMap = {};
    items.forEach((item) => {
      if (!collectionMap[item.collectionName]) {
        collectionMap[item.collectionName] = [item];
      } else {
        collectionMap[item.collectionName].push(item);
      }
    });
  
    return Object.entries(collectionMap).map(([collectionName, collectionItems]) => {
      const firstItem = collectionItems[0]; // Get the first item of the collection
      return (
        <Col key={collectionName}>
          <Card>
            <Card.Img variant="top" src={firstItem.image} />
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>{collectionName}</Card.Title>
              <Link to={`/collection/${collectionName}`}>
                <Button variant="primary">View Collection</Button>
              </Link>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      );
    });
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center">
      <div className="px-5 container">
        <Row xs={1} md={2} lg={4} className="g-4 py-5">
          {renderCollectionCards()}
        </Row>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Collection.js :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Container, Card, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";

const CollectionPage = ({ collectionName, marketplace }) => {
  const [nfts, setNfts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchNFTs = async () => {
      const itemCount = await marketplace.itemCount();
      const nftList = [];

      for (let i = 1; i <= itemCount; i++) {
        const item = await marketplace.items(i);
        if (item.collectionName === collectionName) {
          nftList.push(item);
        }
      }

      setNfts(nftList);
    };

    fetchNFTs();
  }, [collectionName, marketplace]);

  return (
    <Container>
      <h1 className="mt-4 mb-4">Collection: {collectionName}</h1>
      {nfts.length === 0 ? (
        <p>No NFTs available in this collection.</p>
      ) : (
        <Row>
          {nfts.map((nft) => (
            <Col key={nft.itemId} sm={6} md={4} lg={3} className="mb-4">
              <Card>
                <Card.Img variant="top" src={nft.image} />
                <Card.Body>
                  <Card.Title>{nft.name}</Card.Title>
                  <Card.Text>{nft.description}</Card.Text>
                </Card.Body>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          ))}
        </Row>
      )}
    </Container>
  );
};

export default CollectionPage;
```

App.js :

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Navigation from "./Navbar";
import Collection from "./Collection";
import Home from "./Home.js";
import Create from "./Create.js";
import MyListedItems from "./MyListedItems.js";
import MyPurchases from "./MyPurchases.js";
import MarketplaceAbi from "../contractsData/Marketplace.json";
import MarketplaceAddress from "../contractsData/Marketplace-address.json";
import NFTAbi from "../contractsData/NFT.json";
import NFTAddress from "../contractsData/NFT-address.json";
import { useState } from "react";
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import { Spinner } from "react-bootstrap";

import "./App.css";

    function App() {
      const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
      const [account, setAccount] = useState(null);
      const [nft, setNFT] = useState({});
      const [marketplace, setMarketplace] = useState({});
      // MetaMask Login/Connect
      const web3Handler = async () => {
        const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({
          method: "eth_requestAccounts",
        });
        setAccount(accounts[0]);
        // Get provider from Metamask
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
        // Set signer
        const signer = provider.getSigner();
    
        window.ethereum.on("chainChanged", (chainId) => {
          window.location.reload();
        });
    
        window.ethereum.on("accountsChanged", async function (accounts) {
          setAccount(accounts[0]);
          await web3Handler();
        });
        loadContracts(signer);
      };
      const loadContracts = async (signer) => {
        // Get deployed copies of contracts
        const marketplace = new ethers.Contract(
          MarketplaceAddress.address,
          MarketplaceAbi.abi,
          signer
        );
        setMarketplace(marketplace);
        const nft = new ethers.Contract(NFTAddress.address, NFTAbi.abi, signer);
        setNFT(nft);
        setLoading(false);
      };
    
      return (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div className="App">
            <>
              <Navigation web3Handler={web3Handler} account={account} />
            </>
            <div>
              {loading ? (
                <div
                  style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    alignItems: "center",
                    minHeight: "80vh",
                  }}
                >
                  <Spinner animation="grow" style={{ display: "flex" }} />
                  <p className="mx-3 my-0">Awaiting Metamask Connection...</p>
                </div>
              ) : (
                <Routes>
                  <Route
                    path="/"
                    element={<Home marketplace={marketplace} nft={nft} />}
                  />
                  <Route
                    path="/create"
                    element={<Create marketplace={marketplace} nft={nft} />}
                  />
                  <Route
                    path="/my-listed-items"
                    element={
                      <MyListedItems
                        marketplace={marketplace}
                        nft={nft}
                        account={account}
                      />
                    }
                  />
                  <Route
                    path="/my-purchases"
                    element={
                      <MyPurchases
                        marketplace={marketplace}
                        nft={nft}
                        account={account}
                      />
                    }
                  />
                  <Route
                    path="/collection/:collectionName"
                    element={<Collection marketplace={marketplace} />}
                  />
                </Routes>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```